# How does inputting a string into an int variable work in C++

Tags: c++

this is some code that i have in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num1;
    string some;
    cout << "enter something";
    cin >> num1 >> some;
    cout << num1 << endl << some;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a bit confused about how inputting works exactly in C++. First of all, through observation i figured that when asking for multiple inputs, C++ looks for either space or line separated data and am not sure if that is exactly true as websites i have looked at don't say this explicitly. Also my main problem is what happens when for `num1`, which is an integer variable, i input 'hello', which is a string, and click enter. In that case, C++ doesn't even ask me for an input for `some` and instead just outputs 0. I am a beginner in C++ and am very confused why this happens as i would expect an error message instead. I am hoping that someone would explain to me the procedure that C++ goes through when dealing with a situation like this, where a string gets stored in an int variable, to better understand inputting in C++. Thanks!

Comment: Program expects a number but gets not a number, so the input goes into fail mode and nothing is assigned to the variables. You should really take the time to run through the tutorials over at https://learncpp.com — they will answer all these kinds of questions.

Comment: Time to start reading about [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Comment: @Dúthomhas i have read through all of the sections on learncpp.com that include identifiers, variables, iostreams, etc. And it did not help me with my problem. also, thanks for your initial explanation, but can you explain what happens after nothing is assigned to the variables? because it seems like the input stream messes up

Comment: There is an _entire section_ on dealing with invalid input, and the very first lesson helpfully points you to it as well. Give it another read. ;-)

Comment: For me your code works as expected: I'm entering number and then string and getting both printed properly

Comment: @DmitryMesserman yes, if you input a number and then a string it works properly but my question is what exactly happens if you enter a string initially instead of an integer

Comment: @Dúthomhas ok thank you. But next time please provide a link because it took a long time to find that specific section. The introduction to the tutorial didnt specify the chapter number either. But still thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

With "Hello" you are putting the cout and cin into an error state where especially cin doesn't accept any further input.

If you want to prevent the user from writing text instead of numbers, you have to check each input character. There are several functions that can check if a key code equals a number or not.